# Xamarin Firebase package doesn't exist in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, firebase, xamarin.forms, nuget

I have a Xamarin.forms project that requires ML Kit from firebase, so I wanted to download [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.ML.Vision/71.1700.0-preview9) package, Xamarin.Firebase.ML.Vision. The problem is that when I try to add it in Nuget in Visual Studio, the package doesn't show up. How do I get it?

Comment: what does the Nuget console say when you try to add it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's still in preview. You need to enable the Include pre-release for it to show up in nugets
[image: Visual Studio Windows NyGet Package Manager]